# UWP DeviceWatcher raises Added event for powered off device

Tags: c#, bluetooth, uwp

I created a device watcher:

`DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(BluetoothLEDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromDeviceName("..."));`

If the bluetooth device I'm looking for is powered off, an Added event is raised immediately followed by a Removed event.  If it's powered on, I only get an Added event.

Is the device somehow being cached if it was previously found by the watcher, and that's what causes the Added event to be raised despite being powered off?  Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the device somehow being cached if it was previously found by the watcher, and that's what causes the Added event to be raised despite being powered off? Is there a way to prevent this?

The device would not be cached by the watcher, the enumeration of `DeviceWatcher` comes from system level, and it will  take a little time to check the Bluetooth device status change. It is not instant response.

If you want test `DeviceWatcher` please refer to the following steps.

1. Open system Settings --> Devices-->Add Bluetooth or other device-->Bluetooth.

[image]

2. Start your `DeviceWatcher`. You will find that the device info display in the list view quickly. Because the data source of list view comes from system level collection.
3. Stop your `DeviceWatcher` and then stop your bluetooth device until you could not find your bluetooth device info in "Add a device" window.
4. Start your `DeviceWatcher`. You will find the your bluetooth device info would not display again and the application would not raise event as your mentioned

**Note**

For third step, if you start `DeviceWatcher` before the information of bluetooth device disappearing in the "Add a Device" list, then the events execution order will be just like what you mentioned.

Comment: I do not understand how this solves the issue. I'm having a similar, (if not the same) issue where my on program start-up my device watcher populates previously added devices though they are not powered on. After ten seconds the devices are removed (somehow the device watcher recognizes these devices were never actually powered on and removes them automatically, or so I assume). How to handle the device watcher's "cache" of old devices on start-up?

Comment: @jtth I'm facing the same issue, did you manage to solve it?